# change error type in REST api

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, slim

I have prepare RESTful API in php using slim framework. Its works perfectly normal.

but for my code if user miss *REQUEST_METHOD* then its firing **Object not found** error.

For example, for url http://localhost/task_manaager/v1/storeavatar : its request type is *POST* but if we set request type to *GET* it fires **Object not found** error.

I need to customize error handling and use specific error codes and error messages.

Please help me here I am stuck here.

Comment: You should show the related code mate.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by code mate ? @darren

Comment: Well you say you use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, so show us how you use that, and how you send your data to your api.

Comment: I don't actually use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], because I use slim frame work. I use $app->post object for POST request and $app->get for GET request. So I think this will be handle by slim. besides if I set request type GET for post URL its firing this error. I need to change error to "incorrect request type".  and for data send I use  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC  extension for chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single route for different request types like so:

```
$app->map('/task_manaager/v1/storeavatar', function() use ($app){
    if($app->request()->isPost()) {
        //It is a POST request
    } else {
        //It is a GET request
    }
})->via('GET','POST');
```

This is all in the documentation of the Slim framework: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Custom-HTTP-Methods

Comment: Thanks tuim it is best solutions, but is it possible identidy request type and throw error code. because I alredy develope too many calls and it will be really messy to change all for all code. :(

Comment: Don't think so. If you use a middleware you still need to adapt your routes in the app.